# Check HTTP Response

Tags: c#

I'm not catching the error in time, when the web server returns an error: (407) 
My application breaks at the following point

```
           //Get Response
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I am validating the Response to late, how can I test the response without the system crashing?

```
   //Get Response
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Do something 
        }
```

Comment: Is the GetResponse call throwing an exception?

Comment: If *"My application breaks"* means you have [exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx), then you can use [`try/catch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use try catch finally block for validating the Response
as

```
try 
{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch(WebException e) 
   {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nWeb Exception occurred : {0}",e.Status); 
   }
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}",e.Message);
}

}
finally{
//code after checking http response
}
```

I think you should also write following code to avoid exception

```
try{
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
}catch(WebException ex){}
```

and on web.config use this

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

to avoid exception

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the exception:

```
try 
{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex) 
{
    if((ex.Response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == ProxyAuthenticationRequired)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer WebException instead of Exception, and then check the exception code.